# beforesubmit doesn't appear to be executing at all

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I trying to get the beforesubmit option to work so I can validate the form before it is submitted.  I must be missing something.  This runs fine but it totally ignores the function.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            var options = {
                    beforesubmit: function() {
                            var subjectTxtVal = $('input[name=subjectTxt]').fieldValue(); 
                            var messageTxtVal = $('input[name=messageTxt]').fieldValue();

                            if (!subjectTxtVal[0] || !messageTxtVal[0]) { 
                                alert('Please enter a value for subject and message'); 
                                return false; 
                            } 
                    },
                    target:  '#results',
                    success: showResponse
            };
            $('#results').dialog({autoOpen: false, modal: true, buttons: {
                            Ok: function() {
                                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                            }
                    }});
            $('#resemail').submit(function() {
                    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
                    $('#results').dialog('open');
                    return false;
            });

    });
```

Based on my testing with firebug I don't see where it is ever actually calling the function.  I have looked at the docs and the examples but it is somewhat confusing.  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Hard for us to help you as you seem to be using a plugin? We can't tell what's going on in the ajaxSubmit function. Can you post code related to the ajaxSubmit method ?

Comment: The plugin in question is the jquery form plugin (jquery.malsup.com/form/).  I am not sure I follow as to what you are requesting.  The ajaxSubmit function is in the code I posted.  The only piece I left out was the show response function. `        function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
                $('#coursemail').clearForm();
        }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just validate it yourself before submit instead of relying on the plugin ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var options = {
                    target:  '#results',
                    success: showResponse
            };
            $('#results').dialog({autoOpen: false, modal: true, buttons: {
                            Ok: function() {
                                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                            }
                    }});
            $('#resemail').submit(function() {
                    if( validate_fields() )
                    {
                        $(this).ajaxSubmit( options );
                    }
                    else 
                       return false;                                                     
            });

});

function validate_fields() 
{
  var subjectTxtVal = $('input[name=subjectTxt]').fieldValue(); 
  var messageTxtVal = $('input[name=messageTxt]').fieldValue();

  if (!subjectTxtVal[0] || !messageTxtVal[0]) { 
      alert('Please enter a value for subject and message'); 
      return false; 
   }
   return true;  
}
```

Comment: Using the before submit option seemed like the easiest way to validate the form.  The docs specifically say "The 'beforeSubmit' callback can be provided as a hook for running pre-submit logic or for validating the form data."  So it seemed like it would be the best option.  I will take a look at your example.  If it gets the job done that is all that matters.  Thanks.